# Authentication to Kubernetes API of GKE cluster within Google Cloud Function

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-functions, google-kubernetes-engine

What is the best way to authenticate to the Kubernetes API of a GKE cluster in the context of a Google Cloud Function? After digging into the source code of `google-auth-library` and `@kubernetes/client-node`, I came up with the solution below by using some undocumented APIs. It works, but I wonder if this is the right way to do it, and if there is something ready-to-use out there.

It is particularly strange that https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.zones.clusters#MasterAuth also returns clientCertificate and clientKey. Using those for `opts.cert` and `opts.key` instead of the access token lead to the following error:

```
Error from server (Forbidden): namespaces "footest" is forbidden: User "client" cannot delete namespaces in the namespace "footest": Unknown user "client"
```

```js
const { auth } = require('google-auth-library');
const k8s = require('@kubernetes/client-node');

const CLUSTER_ID = 'cluster';
const ZONE = 'us-central1';

async function deleteNamespace(namespace) {
  const cluster = await getCluster(ZONE, CLUSTER_ID);
  const token = await auth.getAccessToken();
  const k8sApi = new k8s.Core_v1Api('https://' + cluster.endpoint);
  k8sApi.setDefaultAuthentication({
    applyToRequest: (opts) => {
      opts.ca = Buffer.from(cluster.masterAuth.clusterCaCertificate, 'base64');
      if (!opts.headers) {
        opts.headers = [];
      }
      opts.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + token;
    },
  });

  await k8sApi.deleteNamespace(namespace, {});
}

async function getCluster(zone, clusterId) {
  const googleApi = await getGoogleApi();
  const projectId = googleApi.projectId;
  const res = await googleApi.client.request({
    url: `https://container.googleapis.com/v1/projects/${projectId}/zones/${zone}/clusters/${clusterId}`,
  });
  return res.data;
}

async function getGoogleApi() {
  const res = await auth.getApplicationDefault();
  const client = res.credential;

  // The createScopedRequired method returns true when running on GAE or a local developer
  // machine. In that case, the desired scopes must be passed in manually. When the code is
  // running in GCE or a Managed VM, the scopes are pulled from the GCE metadata server.
  // See https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/authentication for more information.
  if (client.createScopedRequired && client.createScopedRequired()) {
    // Scopes can be specified either as an array or as a single, space-delimited string.
    const scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'];
    client = client.createScoped(scopes);
  }

  return {
    client: client,
    projectId: res.projectId,
  };
}
```

Comment: Using the certificate method is the right way to call the API. In regards to the error message, this error message is coming from within the cluster. The error message means that you are missing a cluster level permission not allowing you to delete the namespace.

Comment: @Jason is right. This error is coming from Kubernetes. It means that the user you have authenticated as does not have permission to execute the operation on the Kubernetes API

Comment: Did you try to expose a service account of the GKE role and that will be bind to the GCF ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*The error above seems to be due to either the user not being valid or not having the correct permissions.*

You can use the `@google-cloud/container` library to fetch details about your cluster from GKE and use the returned information to set up the configuration in the client for `@kubernetes/client-node`.

> In order to be able to fetch cluster information using the `@google-cloud/container` library, you should have a valid GCP Service Account `JsonKey` file pointed to by an environment variable: `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` .

The following is a code snippet that fetches *cluster credentials* from GKE and subsequently uses the `@kubernetes/client-node` to interact with the K8s API.

This sample provided here follows the explanation provided in these two comments. ([1](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-cloud-container/issues/213#issuecomment-788369671) and [2](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-cloud-container/issues/213#issuecomment-789085877))

```js
const googleContainer = require('@google-cloud/container');
const k8s = require('@kubernetes/client-node');

// Create the Cluster Manager Client
const client = new googleContainer.v1.ClusterManagerClient();

/**
 * The following function is equivalent to the 'get-credentials' call using
 * gcloud. The client assumes that the 'GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'
 * environment variable is set to the json key file associated to your GCP
 * service account (https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#create_service_account).
 *
 * The return values of this method are the credentials that are used to update
 * the k8s config file (~/.kube/config) to add a new context when
 * 'get-credentials' is invoked by the 'gcloud' CLI
 */
async function getCredentials(cluster, zone) {
  const projectId = await client.getProjectId();
  const accessToken = await client.auth.getAccessToken();
  const request = {
    projectId: projectId,
    zone: zone,
    clusterId: cluster
  };

  const [response] = await client.getCluster(request);
  // the following are the parameters added when a new k8s context is created
  return {
    // the endpoint set as 'cluster.server'
    endpoint: response.endpoint,
    // the certificate set as 'cluster.certificate-authority-data'
    certificateAuthority: response.masterAuth.clusterCaCertificate,
    // the accessToken set as 'user.auth-provider.config.access-token'
    accessToken: accessToken
  }
}

async function listServices(cluster, zone) {
  const k8sCredentials = await getCredentials(cluster, zone);
  const k8sClientConfig = new k8s.KubeConfig();
  k8sClientConfig.loadFromOptions({
    clusters: [{
      name: `my-gke-cluster_${cluster}`,            // any name can be used here
      caData: k8sCredentials.certificateAuthority,  // <-- this is from getCredentials call
      server: `https://${k8sCredentials.endpoint}`, // <-- this is from getCredentials call
    }],
    users: [{
      name: `my-gke-cluster_${cluster}`,
      authProvider: 'gcp',                          // the is not a required field
      token: k8sCredentials.accessToken             // <-- this is from getCredentials call
    }],
    contexts: [{
      name: `my-gke-cluster_${cluster}`,
      user: `my-gke-cluster_${cluster}`,
      cluster: `my-gke-cluster_${cluster}`
    }],
    currentContext: `my-gke-cluster_${cluster}`,
  });
  const k8sApi = k8sClientConfig.makeApiClient(k8s.CoreV1Api);
  k8sApi.listNamespacedService('default').then((res) => {
    printServices(res.body.items);
  });
}

function printServices(services) {
  services.forEach(svc => {
    const name = svc.metadata.name;
    const type = svc.spec.type;
    const clusterIp = svc.spec.clusterIP;
    const externalIP = svc.spec.externalIPs || "<none>";
    let ports = "";
    svc.spec.ports.forEach((p) => ports += `${p.port}/${p.protocol},`)
    ports = ports || "<none>"
    console.log(name + "\t" + type + "\t" + clusterIp + "\t" + externalIP + "\t" + ports);
  });
}

// list k8s services in the given cluster and zone
listServices('<CLUSTER>', '<ZONE>');
```

Comment: Good answer, thx. For regional clusters the signature for .getCluster would be to build a name string that resembles `projects/${PROJECT}/locations/${location}/clusters/${cluster}`